# hdfs.init() Error in RHadoop

Tags: r, bigdata, hadoop

"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181")

```
 library(rJava)
 library(rhdfs)
 library(rmr2)

 hdfs.init()After setting up Hadoop single node cluster on my machine, I tried to execute commands using R-Studio in windows. However, I am getting an error message with following code:


 Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="C:/hadoop-2.7.3")

 Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="C:/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop")

 Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME=
```

**Error in .jnew("org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration") : 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**

Comment: I have already downloaded required packages and set the path correctly, but, still getting the error. I have checked my hadoop and java directories are same as mentioned in environment variables. Do I have make any changes in configuration. I am using Windows-7 and R-studio.

Answer (score 0):

I just revisited the installation help sites and found that windows installation requires certain configuration files and then it works exactly fine.